# What does "add years to my life" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Please look at the following:

> Dear Katharine (very dear):
>
> I've had moments of despair during the last week which have **added years to my life** and put many new thoughts in my head. Always, however, I have ended on a cheerful note of hope. based on the realization that you are the person to whom I return and that you are the recurrent phrase in my life.

From *Letters of E.B. White*

From the context here, I think the phrase "add years to life" means that "it makes me worry and makes me feel years older" but I searched everywhere and cannot find another instance where this phrase is used with this meaning.

I have searched all dictionaries I have access to: OED, OALD, Cambridge advanced learner's dictionary, and American Heritage Dictionary, but cannot find the meaning for this phrase.

I also Googled it to try to find how it is used in different contexts. In all the cases I have found, it appears to mean "to make me live longer."

Can someone let me know:

- can the phrase mean "it makes me feel years older?"
- where else is it used with this meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When EB White wrote that the moments of despair added years to his life, he meant that they made him feel years older than his real age.

Comment: That’s what I guessed too, but I cannot find anything else that uses this phrase this way. Nor can i find it in the dictionaries.

Comment: It should be noted that "add years to your life" is often used to mean that the subject item/activity can make you live longer.

Comment: I find a lot of examples that means to make life longer but haven't found another case which means to make one feel older.

Answer (score 3):

**put years on someone** or **put years on (one)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+years+on+someone) idioms

> To cause someone to look, act, or feel much older than they are.

As in:

> I'm not even 30, but having two kids has put years on me!

Comment: My mother used to say "You'll put years on me!" to me and my sister. She also used to say "You'll make me drink Brobat!" Brobat is a UK brand of bleach.